# Combine two queries while keeping all the results

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, join, full-outer-join

I have two tables and I have to combine the results keeping all the results in one dataset.

I tried with the various joins but nothing returns the result.

I need the query for both SQL Server and MS Access.

Example:

TAB_A

```
+---------------------+------+
|       DATAORA       |  P1  |
+---------------------+------+
| 02/05/2020 15:00:30 | 100  |
| 02/05/2020 15:15:30 | 200  |
| 02/05/2020 15:30:30 | 300  |  
| 02/05/2020 15:45:30 | NULL |
| 02/05/2020 16:00:30 | 500  |
+---------------------+------+
```

TAB_B

```
+---------------------+------+
|         ORA         |  P2  |
+---------------------+------+
| 02/05/2020 15:00:30 | 600  |
| 02/05/2020 15:16:30 | 700  |
| 02/05/2020 15:40:30 | NULL |  
| 02/05/2020 15:45:30 | 800  |
| 02/05/2020 15:59:30 | 900  |
+---------------------+------+
```

RESULT

```
+---------------------+------+------+
|       DATAORA       |  P1  |  P2  |
+---------------------+------+------+
| 02/05/2020 15:00:30 | 100  | 600  |
| 02/05/2020 15:15:30 | 200  | NULL |
| 02/05/2020 15:16:30 | NULL | 700  |
| 02/05/2020 15:30:30 | 300  | NULL |
| 02/05/2020 15:40:30 | NULL | NULL |
| 02/05/2020 15:45:30 | NULL | 800  |
| 02/05/2020 15:59:30 | NULL | 900  |
| 02/05/2020 16:00:30 | 500  | NULL |
+---------------------+------+------+
```

Comment: How about a FULL OUTER JOIN?

Comment: Slight detour...you have a couple of great answers already but I feel I should suggest you not use reserved words for object or column names. TIME and TIMESTAMP are both datatypes in sql server. Additionally they are so vague as to be nearly useless column names anyway.

Comment: @SeanLange TIMESTAMP and TIME I used them only to create the example, in the DB they are called DataOra and Data

Comment: Cool I was hoping as much. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are describing is a `full join`. If your RDBMS supports it, then the logic is:

```
select time, a.p1, b.p2
from ( ... query A ...) a
full join ( ... query B ...) b using(time)
```

Note that this assumes that both queries return a column called `time`, which simplifies the syntax.

If your database does not support `full join`s, you can use `union all` and aggregation:

```
select time, max(p1) p1, max(p2) p2
from (
    select time, p1, null from (... query A ...)
    union all select time, p1, null from (... query B ...)
) t
group by time
```

Comment: @P13TR0: in which database are you running the query?

Comment: sql server 2005 but I need the query for both SQL Server and MS Access

Comment: SQL Server 2005 is a really old version; it supports `full join`s by maybe not the `using` syntax. And Access does not support `full join` anyway. If you want a query that runs on both databases, try the second one.

Answer (score 2):

How about a PIVOT

**Example**

```
Select *
 From  (
        Select DATAORA,P1,Item = 'P1' From Tab_A
        Union All
        Select ORA    ,P2,Item = 'P2' From Tab_B
       ) src
 Pivot (sum(P1) for Item in ([P1],[P2]) ) pvt
```